# i am trying to use starflut package in flutter but i am getting a lot of exceptions which i am unable to configure it

Tags: flutter

I am trying to import starflut package in flutter but i am getting a lot of exceptions which i am not able to solve.I have copy pasted the file according to (https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter).

Use this line to run the code in terminal :**flutter run --no-sound-null-safety**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnDkb.png)

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:starflut/starflut.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: const MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          await initpla();
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 350,
          height: 500,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initpla() async {
    try {
      StarCoreFactory starcore = await Starflut.getFactory();
      StarServiceClass Service =
          await starcore.initSimple("test", "123", 0, 0, []);
      await starcore.regMsgCallBackP(
          (int serviceGroupID, int uMsg, Object wParam, Object lParam) async {
        print("$serviceGroupID  $uMsg   $wParam   $lParam");

        return null;
      });
      dynamic SrvGroup = await Service["_ServiceGroup"];
      bool isAndroid = await Starflut.isAndroid();
      if (isAndroid == true) {
        //desRelatePath must be null
        await Starflut.loadLibrary("libpython3.9.so");

        await Starflut.copyFileFromAssets(
            "python3.9.zip", "flutter_assets/starflut", null);

        var nativepath = await Starflut.getNativeLibraryDir();
        print("Nativepath : $nativepath");
        var LibraryPath = "";
        if (nativepath.contains("x86_64"))
          LibraryPath = "x86_64";
        else if (nativepath.contains("arm64"))
          LibraryPath = "arm64";
        else if (nativepath.contains("arm"))
          LibraryPath = "armeabi";
        else if (nativepath.contains("x86")) LibraryPath = "x86";

        await Starflut.copyFileFromAssets(
            "zlib.cpython-39.so", LibraryPath, null);
        await Starflut.copyFileFromAssets(
            "unicodedata.cpython-39.so", LibraryPath, null);

        String docPath = await Starflut.getDocumentPath();
        print("docPath = $docPath");
        String resPath = await Starflut.getResourcePath();
        print("resPath = $resPath");
        dynamic rr1 = await SrvGroup.initRaw("python39", Service);

        var Result = await SrvGroup.loadRawModule(
            "python", "", resPath + "/" + "abc.py", false);
        print("loadRawModulee = $Result");
        dynamic python =
            await Service.importRawContext(null, "python", "", false, "");

        await SrvGroup.clearService();
        await starcore.moduleExit();
        String platformVersion = 'Python 3.9';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("{$e.message}");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter was last updated 2 years ago. It is probably just not compatible with the latest Flutter and Dart.

Comment: Also, it looks like it can't load native libraries (the .so files)

Comment: Is there any way to solve the issue?Btw it contain files of python 3.9 version so in my opinion they may have tested it before uploading.

Comment: Maybe you should try to contact the starflut authors directly?

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I contact them as i am unable to find any option to contact them

Comment: srplab.cn AT hotmail.com according to https://web.archive.org/web/20200809210112/http://www.srplab.info/